# Dart, SASS: importing files located in the web/ directory

Tags: import, sass, dart

I have created a `general.scss` file and placed it under the `web/config` folder. And I would like to import that file from any other SASS files. But the following script doesn't work:

```
// anyotherfile.scss
@import 'web/config/general';
```

The previous command throws the following error:

> Build error: Transform Sass on axis_mobile|lib/app_router.scss threw
>   error: could not resolve import 'Instance of '_SassImport'' (tried
>   [axis_mobile|lib/config/general.scss,
>   axis_mobile|lib/config/general.sass,
>   axis_mobile|lib/config/_general.scss,
>   axis_mobile|lib/config/_general.sass]) null

How could I import a file located under the `web/` directory?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't import from `web/`, at least not if the importing file is outside `web/`.

Files that are supposed to be imported from different directories got to `lib/` or one of its subdirectories.

For files in `/lib` there is always a canonical path using the `packages/mypackage/somefile` that points to the `lib/somefile` of `mypackage` where `mypackage` is the name of the package in the `pubspec.yaml` file of the current project.

This way also files can also be imported if the project is a dependency of another project while other directories are not supported.